# How do I import a Transform object from Ember Data for extending

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I would like to extend Ember Data's `date` model field (https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/addon/transforms/date.js). How do I import this object into a `transforms/` file in my project? I have tried the following:

```
import DateTransform from 'ember-data/transforms/date';

export default DateTransform.extend({
    [deserialize and serialize overridden methods here]
});
```

This does not work, and does not provide any sort of error in console. I feel like I simply have something wrong with the file path in the import statement, but I cannot figure out what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
import DateTransform from 'ember-data/-private/transforms/date'
```